# Java Console not working: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, dll, compiler-errors, runtime-error

So I have Eclipse 3.7.1, running on a 64-bit Windows 7 OS. For the first time in a while yesterday I tried writing a program and kept getting the above error. I refined my program down to a bare minimum beginners tutorial and was still getting the error. My program now is a simple readInt()s and add them together.

The code:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class DBEditor extends ConsoleProgram {

public void main() {
     System.out.println("This adds two integers");
     int a = readInt("First Num: ");
     int b = readInt("Second Num: ");
     int total = a+ b;
     System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is: " + total);
}

}
```

the error when trying to run as Java Application:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
C:\Users\scarr\GCMDLN.DLL: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)   
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)    
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)    
    at acm.program.DOSCommandLine.getCommandLine(Program.java)  
    at acm.program.Program.getCommandLine(Program.java)     
    at acm.program.Program.main(Program.java)
```

How do i fix this? I am fairly rusty, so the more detailed step by step fix, the better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your DOSCommandLine class?

Comment: `acm.program.DOSCommandLine` is your class or from a lib?

Comment: its from a library. The acm jar includes that class. It is not a class that I created.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the error you're getting is because something in your code tries to load a native library (DLL) and the library you have is for 32 bit Windows while you're running in 64 bit.

Take a look at the `DosCommandLine.getCommandLine()` method in `Program.java` for clues. If you absolutely need functionality provided by that library then you could download the 32 bit JRE and try to run it with it.

Comment: the DosCommandLine method is a part of the acm jar file which my application is associated with. It is nothing that i have created. All that i have created, is the one method included in my original post...

Comment: @Utopia025 ok but, the `DosCommandLine` or something inside the jar are trying to load a 32 bit library.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to the 32 bit JRE when executing works for me. Below are the steps on how to do this exactly in Eclipse:

- Go to *Run*
- Go to *Run configurations*
- Under the *JRE* tab you can switch to the 32 bit JRE

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are using a .dll file for a 32bit version, while your JDK and platform are 64bit.
Go to your path "C:\Users\scarr" and you will find 2 subfolders, i386, and x64. Copy the GCMDLN.DLL from the x64 or the current .dll file, to override it.
I think the issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem with a wrong declaration of the main or run method.
In standard java:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
}
```

Using ConsoleProgram from the acm library I think you should be:

```
public void run() {
}
```

So `run()` Instead of `main()`. So nothing to do with the **64bit jre**.